# Kafka kafka.common.MessageSizeTooLargeException at consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

For some larger messages I encountered the following error:

```
kafka.common.MessageSizeTooLargeException: Message size is 1185198 bytes which exceeds the maximum configured message size of 1000012.
```

So as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/kafka-sending-a-15mb-message) increased the message size at broker and consumer:

```
fetch.message.max.bytes=10485760
replica.fetch.max.bytes=10485760
message.max.bytes=10485760
```

added to `config/server.properties`

But then the messages goes through but consumer error out:

```
[2015-08-26 21:08:08,722] ERROR Error processing message, stopping consumer:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$)
kafka.common.MessageSizeTooLargeException: Found a message larger than the maximum fetch size of this consumer on topic xyz partition 0 at fetch offset 29. Increase the fetch size, or decrease the maximum message size the broker will allow.
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:90)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:33)
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.maybeComputeNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.hasNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:660)
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.foreach(IteratorTemplate.scala:32)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at kafka.consumer.KafkaStream.foreach(KafkaStream.scala:25)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:166)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
Consumed 3 messages
```

It seems the consumer is not picking up `fetch.message.max.bytes=10485760`

kafka_2.9.1-0.8.2.1

Any pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't put `fetch.message.max.bytes` to `config/server.properties` but to your `ConsumerConfig` (see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example) for details). If you are using console consumer you may pass a `--consumer.config consumer.properties` flag where consumer.properties file will contain this config value.

Comment: How can I get Storm spout to obey the higher fetch size. Any idea? @serejja

Comment: @KedarParikh no idea, never used Storm that deep before

Comment: SpoutConfig.fetchSizeBytes seems to be the option

Comment: Passing --consumer.config consumer.properties works but when I tried to put that file in the same folder where server.properties lies, it does not work. Did i miss anything?

Comment: @Sujan probably because console consumer does not scan config directory for consumer properties