# What does "offsets.topic.compression.codec" in kafka actually do?

Tags: apache-kafka, compression, kafka-consumer-api

Very recently we started to get MessageSizeTooLargeException on the metadata, so we enabled offsets.topic.compression.codec=1, to enable gzip compression, but the overall bytes in rate/messages in rate to the broker hasnt changed. Am i missing something? Is there some other property which needs to be changed?

How does this codec work?

Do we need to add some property on consumers and producers as well? I have just enabled this on the broker.

Answer (score 1):

`offsets.topic.compression.codec` is only for the internal offset topic (namely __consumer_offsets). It is no use for those user-level topics.

See [Kafka: Sending a 15MB message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/kafka-sending-a-15mb-message) on how to avoid MessageTooLargeException/RecordTooLargeException.