# Error configuring .NET producer client of Apache Kafka to work with big messages

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm using a [.NET client (producer and consumer) of Apache Kafka](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet).

I'm trying to increase the size of the max message that can be sent. I read the [configuration manual](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#configuration) and some posts regarding my issue:

1. [Kafka: Sending a 15MB message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/kafka-sending-a-15mb-message)
2. https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest/issues/208

I saw that I should set the property "max.request.size" for the producer.
So I did the following:

```
   var config = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "bootstrap.servers", brokerList },
            { "max.request.size", 10 * 1024 * 1024 }
        };

        using (var producer = new Producer<Null, string>(config, null, new StringSerializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
        {
         ...
```

But when I run the Producer, an exception is thrown :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No such configuration property: "max.request.size"'
```

The Apache Kafka documentation tells the following about this property of the producer:

> The maximum size of a request in bytes. This is also effectively a cap
>   on the maximum record size. Note that the server has its own cap on
>   record size which may be different from this. This setting will limit
>   the number of record batches the producer will send in a single
>   request to avoid sending huge requests.

If, for some reason the documentation isn't up-to-date, what is the right property to use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

confluent-kafka-dotnet uses librdkafka under the hood which has a different set of configuration parameters to the java client. These are documented here:

https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md

I believe the parameter you are looking for is `message.max.bytes`