# kafka broker is not gzipping my bigger size message , even though i specified compression type in the producer configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, jms, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

Below are my producer configuration , where if you see their is compression type as gzip , even though i mentioned the compression type why the message is not publishing and it is failing with

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, edi856KafkaConfig.getBootstrapServersConfig());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, edi856KafkaConfig.getRetriesConfig());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, edi856KafkaConfig.getBatchSizeConfig());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, edi856KafkaConfig.getIntegerMsConfig());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, edi856KafkaConfig.getBufferMemoryConfig());
        ***props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");***
        props.put(Edi856KafkaProducerConstants.SSL_PROTOCOL, edi856KafkaConfig.getSslProtocol());
        props.put(Edi856KafkaProducerConstants.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, edi856KafkaConfig.getSecurityProtocol());
        props.put(Edi856KafkaProducerConstants.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION, edi856KafkaConfig.getSslKeystoreLocation());
        props.put(Edi856KafkaProducerConstants.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD, edi856KafkaConfig.getSslKeystorePassword());
        props.put(Edi856KafkaProducerConstants.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION, edi856KafkaConfig.getSslTruststoreLocation());
        props.put(Edi856KafkaProducerConstants.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD, edi856KafkaConfig.getSslTruststorePassword());
        **props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "gzip");**
```

and error am getting is below

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 1170632 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration.
2017-12-07_12:34:10.037 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR c.tgt.trans.producer.Edi856Producer - Exception while writing mesage to topic= '{}'
org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 1170632 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration.
```

and want consumer configuration we need to use of i want string representation of the kafka message on the consumer side

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately you're encountering a rather odd issue with the new Producer implementation in Kafka.

Although the messages size limit applied by Kafka at the broker level is applied to a single *compressed* record set (potentially multiple messages), the new producer currently applies the `max.request.size` limit on the record prior to any compression.

This has been captured in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4169 (created 14/Sep/16 and unresolved at time of writing).

If you are *certain* that the compressed size of your message (plus any overhead of the record set) will be smaller than the broker's configured `max.message.bytes`, you *may* be able to get away with increasing the value of `max.request.size` property on your Producer *without* having to change any configuration on the broker. This would allow the Producer code to accept the size of the pre-compression payload where it would then be compressed and sent to the broker.

However it is important to note that should the Producer try to send a request that is too large for the configuration of the broker, the broker will reject the message and it will be up to your application to handle this correctly.

Comment: Confirming that in kafka python creating the Producer as `KafkaProducer(compression_type='gzip',
                                 max_request_size=2 ** 20 * 10) # 10 MBs` gets the message through

Answer (score 1):

Just read the error message :)

`The message is 1170632 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration`

The message is > 1 MByte that is the default value allowed by Apache Kafka. To allow large messages check the answers in [How can I send large messages with Kafka (over 15MB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb)

Comment: i am just producer , i can not change broker side configuration , i already checked those broker side configuration , but i do not have access to broker, am still producer only .

Comment: sorry - but you need access to the broker config :(