# Error MessageSizeTooLargeError on Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I'm learning Kafka and, while doing a simple exercise, I received the error MessageSizeTooLargeError.
The problem is that the message sent by producer to consumer is too big.

I tried to change some parameters into configuration files but I didn't resolve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've resolved the problem, changing some parameters

Comment: What is your current configuration?

Comment: Now I've the default configuration

Comment: How big is your message ? Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb) ?

Comment: @En1gma As you've edited your answer, as in, you got the solution, if I'm not wrong. Please do post the answer so that in future if anyone is trying to search for the same, then they'll be able to use it. **Spread the knowledge.** Cheers!