# Not able to consume large messages with Kafka (over 1.3 MB)?

Tags: python, node.js, apache-kafka

I followed the link [How can I send large messages with Kafka (over 15MB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb) to resolve the kafka msg limit issue. But no luck

I tried increasing

A.) On Broker:

```
message.max.bytes=15728640 
replica.fetch.max.bytes=15728640
```

B.) On Consumer: `fetch.message.max.bytes=15728640`

Still facing the same problem. Not able to consume data that is over 1.3 MB on a particular topic

In my application, a msg in sent on a topic from python code and is consumed on node server.

Comment: Were you able to send them without error, and you just cannot consume them?

Comment: I am able to send and getting problem at consuming the message

Answer (score 2):

`Kafka` does have strict restriction over the size of data; default is `1MB`.
I believe you have missed topic level config.

There are multiple configs at different levels:

You have a broker setting `message.max.bytes` (default is 1000012) http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

There is a topic level config `max.message.bytes` (default is 1000012) 
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs

Producer has `max.request.size` (default is 1048576) 
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs

Consumer has `max.partition.fetch.bytes` (default is 1048576)
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs