# Cant send large kafka message

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming

I'm attempting to send a 10770128 byte message over Kafka. I am receiving the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 10770128 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration.
```

I've gone through and added the following settings to server.properties, producer.properties, and consumer.properties.

```
replica.fetch.max.bytes =12000000
message.max.bytes=12000000
max.message.bytes=12000000
max.request.size=12000000
max.message.max.bytes=12000000
max.partition.fetch.bytes=12000000
```

this is a three node kafka cluster. Each node has the above settings in each file. Any help is appreciated. Thank you :)

Edit: I have already attempted the configurations seen [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb), yet the problem persists

Comment: I assume you restarted the cluster after editing the property files?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I restarted all the broker nodes. I did not restart the zookeeper nodes. I also have configured all the settings in the possible duplicate that you mentioned.

Comment: Don't need to edit Zookeeper. I assume you are using a regular Java client, no Spring Boot, Spark, etc?

Comment: The producer is a spring boot app, however there are no producer settings anywhere on the project.

Comment: But you mentioned you have a `producer.properties`? In any case, you will have to change the producer settings within that project

Comment: the producer.properties exists in the kafka configs directory. I changed the settings in there for posterity.

Comment: Sure, but that is meant for `kafka-console-producer`, not any application that happens to run on the same machine