# Send/Process a image(.png or .jpg) from kafkaProducer to kafkaConsumer?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm pretty new to kakfa/spark-streaming. My use case is to send a image through kafka producer and capture it from kafka consumer.
I did some research and found out that image must be converted to binary or byte format, but couldn't find any proper sources to continue with it.

What i have done so far:

```
1.Started zookeeper
2.Started server
3.created a new topic
4.started a producer to send(eg: JSON) - kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic send_json < materials.json
5.started a consumer to recieve
```

How can i send a .jpg or .png file in a similar way?
Lang : scala or pyspark

Answer (score 1):

Minimal example (scala):

```
val props = new Properties()
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongSerializer")
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer")

val producer = new KafkaProducer(props)
val data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/file"))

val record = new ProducerRecord[Long, Array[Byte]]("yourtopic" , data)
producer.send(record)
producer.close
```

If your images get's bigger keep this one in mind [How can I send large messages with Kafka (over 15MB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb)

---

If you want to use the kafka-console-producer:

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic my_topic < my_file.txt
```

Comment: Should I implement this in producer console

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. You can see two independent examples. Use the scala snippet in your application or put it into the main function of an object to run it standalone. The console consumer can be run as it is.

Comment: Sorry @Anthony what exactly are you looking for? A command-line tool? Or a scala code snippet? Both are present. Pick whatever you want

Comment: There's no LongSerializer under org.apache.kafka.common.serialization?

Comment: Yes only stringSerializer and stringdeserializer , serializer and deserilazer, bytearrayserializer and bytearraydeserializer.

Comment: It is part of the kafka-client lib

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/H0megxj

Comment: How to conert that byteArray back to image?

Comment: How does serialisation helps in this use case?