# Max length for Kafka Key

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a max length for Kafka keys?? I am having issues while pushing data to Kafka. It says connection timeout. Can it because the length of key is too long?? I tried debugging it but could not think of any other reason.

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/21020347/9291522
However, I don't think that a too large payload would result in a connection timeout..

Comment: does it timeout if you don't specify a key or specify a short one?

Comment: I don't think that connection timeout correlate with key length.
You might found this article helpful if you're hosting kafka and zookeeper in docker - https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/