# Kafka Console Producer message size

Tags: apache-kafka, console

I am using Kafka Console Producer to post a JSON message on a kafka topic. The JSON payload is pretty huge. It seems that Kafka Console producer has a size limit on the message it can deliver to Kafka. Is that true?

Small JSON messages on the same topic are working fine. It doesn't even allow me to paste the entire JSON message on the Kafka Console Producer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How you pass message to Kafka Consoler Producer, (redirection from file, paste from clipboard)? What is sample size of the message, that is not _deliver_? What does it mean _deliver, Is message truncate or not sent at all?

Comment: I think that through this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb) you can find answers to your questions.