# Kafka - Broker: Message size too large

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I get `Message size too large` exception, when I try to send a message which is over 1 Mb size. The error appears in my client application, when I try to produce a message. After a little googling I found out that the settings should be changed in order to increase max message size. Well, I did that in `/kafka/config/server.properties` file. I added next 2 settings:

```
message.max.bytes=15728640
replica.fetch.max.bytes=15728640
```

Also, I added `fetch.message.max.bytes=15728640` to the `/kafka/config/consumer.properties` file. All other settings remain default.

I did kafka server restart, but I'm still getting the same error.

P.S Kafka version is 1.1.0.

Comment: Did you look at this question in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb)?

Comment: Do you refer to some specific point from the mentioned link? Because, I did configuration exactly like stated there. Am I missed something?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have the right configuration however you need to also set  **max.request.size** on the producer side.

> `props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, 15728640);`
>
> **max.request.size** The maximum size of a request in bytes. This setting will limit the number of record batches the producer will send
> in a single request to avoid sending huge requests. This is also effectively a cap on the maximum record batch size.

On the Broker side, you have already configured the below parameter that should work

> **message.max.bytes** The largest record batch size allowed by Kafka.
>
> **replica.fetch.max.bytes** The number of bytes of messages to attempt to fetch for each partition. This is not an absolute maximum if the
> first record batch in the first non-empty partition of the fetch is
> larger than this value, the record batch will still be returned to
> ensure that progress can be made. The maximum record batch size
> accepted by the broker is defined via message.max.bytes (broker
> config) or max.message.bytes (topic config).

On the topic side max.message.bytes which is not required in case you have already set message.max.bytes in the broker side

> **max.message.bytes** - this is the largest size of the message the broker
> will allow being appended to the topic. This size is validated
> pre-compression. (Defaults to broker's message.max.bytes.)

Refrence
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/

Comment: Setting message.max.bytes for producer on the client side does a trick. Thank you, sir!

Comment: I had to set max.message.bytes on the topic level

Comment: In my case, using `confluent_kafka`, which is based on `librdkafka`, the producer needs to set the config: `'message.max.bytes` instead. HTH
Reference: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/325

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to set [batch.size](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_batch.size) too.

I got a similar problem. I created a topic with `max.message.bytes=4096`, and I used `kafka-producer-perf-test.sh` for testing. I also set `max.request.size=4096`, but it seems does work properly.

If I go with just one message, it's fine.

```
./kafka/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --producer-props bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 max.request.size=4096 --record-size 4008 --topic test-4K-1RF-topic-0 --num-records 1 --throughput 1
```

If I go with just more than one message, I will get MESSAGE_TOO_LARGE error.

```
./kafka/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --producer-props bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 max.request.size=4096 --record-size 4008 --topic test-4K-1RF-topic-0 --num-records 2 --throughput 1
```

So I guess it is about batch size. Then, I found [batch.size](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_batch.size)

so the below snippet is working now!

```
./kafka/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --producer-props bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 batch.size=4096 --record-size 4008 --topic test-4K-1RF-topic-0 --num-records 200 --throughput 10
```

**Edited:** I think `max.request.size` is to limit the size of a package that a producer sent to a Kafka broker. A package can consist of multiple batches. The batch size is limited by `batch.size`.