# How to overwrite default config values in kafka for confluent-python client?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

As a beginner, I'm exploring Apache Kafka and confluent-kafka-python clients. When I tried to send simple messages from the producer, the consumer was able to consume messages successfully. Thought that I would give it a try for sending the image as payload. So going forward with a 1MB(png) image, my producer was unable to produce messages. The error which I encountered was

```
  p.produce('mytopic', callback=delivery_report, key='hello', value=str_value)
cimpl.KafkaException: KafkaError{code=MSG_SIZE_TOO_LARGE,val=10,str="Unable to produce message: Broker: Message size too large"}
```

Though i did some googling found out [Kafka - Broker: Message size too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59322133/kafka-broker-message-size-too-large)   and
[How can I send large messages with Kafka (over 15MB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb)
So i have modified my server.props(broker side) as shown below:

```
############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0
max.message.bytes=1048576 
message.max.bytes=1048576 
replica.fetch.max.bytes=1048576
```

But still I was unable to fix the issue.

**producer.py**

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer
import base64
import time

# some_data_source = ['hey', 'hi']

with open("1mb.png", "rb") as imageFile:
    str_value = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())

p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'compression.type': 'snappy'})

def delivery_report(err, msg):
    """ Called once for each message produced to indicate delivery result.
        Triggered by poll() or flush(). """
    if err is not None:
        print('Message delivery failed: {}'.format(err))
    else:
        print('Message delivered to {} [{}]'.format(msg.topic(), msg.partition()))

for _ in range(2):
    # Trigger any available delivery report callbacks from previous produce() calls
    p.poll(0)

    # Asynchronously produce a message, the delivery report callback
    # will be triggered from poll() above, or flush() below, when the message has
    # been successfully delivered or failed permanently.
    p.produce('mytopic', callback=delivery_report, key='hello', value=str_value)

# Wait for any outstanding messages to be delivered and delivery report
# callbacks to be triggered.
p.flush()
```

**consumer.py**

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer


c = Consumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
    'group.id': 'mygroup',
    'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'
})

c.subscribe(['mytopic'])

while True:
    msg = c.poll(1.0)

    if msg is None:
        continue
    if msg.error():
        print("Consumer error: {}".format(msg.error()))
        continue

    print('Received message: {}'.format(msg.value().decode('utf-8')))

c.close()
```

Do I need to add any params or Am I missing something in configs ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you changed the broker defaults very much; it's still around 1MB.

For your client errors, you need to add `message.max.bytes` to the Producer config

If you need any other client properties, such as the consumer max fetch bytes, those are documented here

https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md

---

Overall, the recommendation would be to upload your images to a centralized filestore, then send their URI location via Kafka as plain strings. This will increase throughput and reduce storage needs for your brokers, especially if you're sending/copying the same image data over multiple topics

Comment: just added 'message.max.bytes': '10485780', in producer config, working very fast! Thanks@OneCricketeer