# How to set the max size of a Kafka message using librdkafka

Tags: apache-kafka, librdkafka

I'm trying to use Kafka to send a message of ~10Mb.  I know its default size is 1Mb, but is that a hard limit?  Can librdkafka support >10Mb and how do I set it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to configure the topic `max.message.bytes` (see https://kafka.apache.org/22/documentation.html#topicconfigs), and configure the producer with `message.max.bytes` (see https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md).
Please allow some extra space (at least ~500 bytes) for protocol overhead.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply.  I tried doing this, and I no longer received the error stating that the message was too big.  But it seems to hang now.  So what I did was I modified the preexisting topic via the scripts in you reply, I also created a brand new one just to be safe.  Both of which using 15Mb size (to be extra safe).  Now when i modify the code to invoke the max change, it doesn't error anymore but everything above 1Mb will just stop.  The producer is running on its own thread so i can still do things and try to send more messages.  But none are going through

Comment: A bit of reconnaissance shows that I can successful send 9998999 bytes (9.9 Mb and its pretty fast too).  But anything more than that follows the following comment where it just hangs and no longer produces @Edenhill

Comment: Reproduce this with `debug=msg,protocol` configured on the producer and then open an issue here: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/new    Make sure you are using the latest version of librdkafka (v1.3.0 or v1.4.0-RC4)

Comment: Hey @Edenhill, wasn't familiar with your debug stuff so when i ran it i received a bunch of: No more space in current MessageSet, but when i googled it, all i got was references to your github... so maybe I am not using the most up to date, i thought.  I used apt to install from a repo and although had your source never compiled it directly.  Well doing that and linking, fixed it all.  Evidently i wasn't using the most up-to-date.  Also your name appears a lot so i think you are 'the guy'.  Your code has been a pleasure to look through and the documentation is among the best. thank you!

Comment: @Edenhill "Please allow some extra space (at least ~500 bytes) for protocol overhead." -> THIS is useful. I was wondering why with all limits set to 1 MB I cannot send a message with the size of 999908 bytes, but 999907 was OK :)

Comment: Fun fact: if I send a message to a topic with a shorter name, the size of the message can be greater than aforementioned 999907 bytes. Obviously, the topic name counts for this "protocol overhead".