# Kafka Producer limits producer messages to 1024 bytes

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to produce kafka message using the terminal. I downloaded this version `kafka_2.12-2.4.1.tgz`. I tried to start the Zookeeper server and then the the Kafka server. I have a json which is more than 1024 bytes. It's not allowed to send more than 1024 bytes.

I tried to refer to [How can I send large messages with Kafka (over 15MB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb). But that didn't help. Not sure if I am missing any config change.

**Producer Config**

```
max.request.size=2147483647 
socket.buffer.size=2147483647
```

**Server Config**

```
socket.request.max.bytes=2147483647
replica.fetch.max.bytes=2147483647
message.max.bytes=2147483647
max.message.bytes=2147483647
replica.fetch.max.bytes=2147483647
```

**Consumer Config**

```
max.request.size=2147483647
fetch.message.max.bytes=2147483647
max.partition.fetch.bytes=2147483647
```

Comment: provide your producer configuration

Comment: @bottaio : Added the configs

Answer (score 3):

You should increase `max.partition.fetch.bytes` consumer config parameter too for **receiving** large messages.

> **max.partition.fetch.bytes:** The maximum amount of data per-partition the server will return. Records are fetched in batches
> by the consumer. If the first record batch in the first non-empty
> partition of the fetch is larger than this limit, the batch will still
> be returned to ensure that the consumer can make progress. The maximum
> record batch size accepted by the broker is defined via
> message.max.bytes (broker config) or max.message.bytes (topic config).
> See fetch.max.bytes for limiting the consumer request size.