# How to add compression in Kafka producer

Tags: compression, kafka-producer-api

I am new to kafka and have tried methods present online , like putting property compression.type="snappy"(even gzip and lz4). compression.codec=snappy . Still it's not working.
I tried to put linger.ms = 5000 and then the compression type.
But nothing of above is working.The message size is not getting compressed.

Comment: can you add more detail about what tool and how do you check the size of the produced messages?

Comment: I had added logger to check the size . The exception is thrown that the size of the message has  exceeded. Its size is 1mb

Comment: By default, kafka producer check the uncompressed message size against max.request.size even if compression.type is defined. Possible duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb

Comment: You can try increase Producer config max.request.size, if the compressed message is still greater than message.max.bytes then you have to increase broker level configs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I send large messages with Kafka (over 15MB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb)