# kafka stream state store issue with max.request.size paramater

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are using Kafka streams state store in the project, and we want to store more than 1MB of data, but we got below exception:

> The message is 1760923 bytes when serialized which is larger than the
>   maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size
>   configuration.

Then I followed the link [Add prefix to StreamsConfig to enable setting default internal topic configs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-173%3A+Add+prefix+to+StreamsConfig+to+enable+setting+default+internal+topic+configs) and added the following config:

```
topic.max.request.size=50000000
```

Then application works fine, and it can works fine when state store internal topic had been created but when Kafka been restarted and the state store topic had been lost/delete, then the Kafka stream processor need to create the internal state store topic automatically when start the application, at that moment, it throw exception which says:

```
"Aorg.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Could not create topic data-msg-seq-state-store-changelog. at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopicManager.makeReady(InternalTopicManager.java:148)....
.....
org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:805) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:774) Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Unknown topic config name: max.request.size".
```

The solution is we can manually create the internal topic, but that should not be good one.

Can you help me on this issue? If there is any config I have missed?

Thanks very much.

17 June 2020 update: still not resolve the issue. anyone can help?

Comment: `max.request.size` is a producer config, not a topic config: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#max.request.size

Comment: yes. is it means I need to config this for producer on broker? or I misunderstand something. since it's internal topic.

Comment: It means, you need to configure it on the producer. -- Internally, Kafka Streams uses the Kafka cosumer/producer/admin client and you can configure them as if you use those clients directly: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#ak-consumers-producer-and-admin-client-configuration-parameters

Comment: actually i have configed the max.request.size for the producer, and if i not config it for internal topic(changelog), then it will throw exception.

Answer (score 6):

The solution that you are looking for lies in the Kafka Stream's configuration properties that you set before starting the stream.

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.PRODUCER_PREFIX + ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, "5242880");
```

> The value I used here is 5 MB in bytes. You can change the value to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a configuration with `max.request.size`. May be it is **max.message.bytes** ([Topic configuration reference](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html#max.message.bytes)). So, you may try setting this.

You can refer to the broker setting [max.message.bytes](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html#message.max.bytes) and increase it. It sets it at the broker level.

**Documentation states:**

> The largest record batch size allowed by Kafka (after compression if
>   compression is enabled). If this is increased and there are consumers
>   older than 0.10.2, the consumers' fetch size must also be increased so
>   that the they can fetch record batches this large. In the latest
>   message format version, records are always grouped into batches for
>   efficiency. In previous message format versions, uncompressed records
>   are not grouped into batches and this limit only applies to a single
>   record in that case.This can be set per topic with the topic level
>   max.message.bytes config.

Default: 1048588 (~1Mb) (Confluent Kafka)

Also refer to the following [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21343878/2534090)

Comment: Thank your reply. i also do not see this config in the code. but i have question is when i not add this parameter, why it throw exception saying: "The message is 1760923 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the **max.request.size** configuration.". where it mentions 'max.request.size'.

Comment: Thank your reply.

Comment: Which version of Kafka are you using?

Comment: version is: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.2.1

Comment: `max.request.size` is a producer config, not a topic config: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#max.request.size