# RecordTooLargeException in kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

the following is kafka publishing code which is giving **RecordTooLargeException** exception.

tried all possible solutions given in stackoverflow giving info about different properties like max.request.size etc. but nothing worked. exact stack trace is

`Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 1696090 bytes when serialized which is larger than 1048576, which is the value of the max.request.size configuration`.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < 8000; i++) {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            object.put("no", 1);
            object.put("name", "Kella Vivek");
            object.put("salary", 1000);
            object.put("address", "2-143");
            object.put("city", "gpm");
            object.put("pin", 534316);
            object.put("dist", "west");
            object.put("state", "ap");
            object.put("username", "mff");
            object.put("password", "mff");
            array.add(object);
        }

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String string = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(array);

        template.send("consume", string);

    }
```

Comment: Check [this](http://www.alternatestack.com/development/app-development/kafka-message-size-issue-record-too-long-to-send) out. Hope it helps 

Comment: This is general Apache Kafka question. There is just nothing with Spring to do.

Comment: See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-kafka-extra-props. But again: the "too large" problem is out of Spring scope.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I send large messages with Kafka (over 15MB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a spring problem. You need to tweak a number of parameters in kafka producer to make this working.

Now to answer your question I did the following to enable sending 100 mb messages.

Create the properties and set size for buffer.memory, message.max.bytes and max.request.size as per your requirements.

```
Properties producerProperties = new Properties();
producerProperties.put("buffer.memory", 104857600);
producerProperties.put("message.max.bytes", 104857600);
producerProperties.put("max.request.size", 104857600);
producerProperties.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServers);
producerProperties.put("acks", "all");
producerProperties.put("retries", 0);
producerProperties.put("batch.size", 16384);
producerProperties.put("linger.ms", 1);
producerProperties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
producerProperties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

Create Producer using the above properties:

```
KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(producerProperties);
```

And now send.

```
private static void sendKafkaMessage(String payload,
         KafkaProducer<String, String> producer,
         String topic)
{
    logger.info("Sending Kafka message: " + payload);
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, payload));
}
```

You also need to ensure that the target server supports huge messages too. I configured following in the server for supporting huge messages.

```
auto.create.topics.enable=true
default.replication.factor=3
min.insync.replicas=2
num.io.threads=8
num.network.threads=5
num.partitions=1
num.replica.fetchers=2
replica.lag.time.max.ms=30000
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
unclean.leader.election.enable=true
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=18000
replica.fetch.max.bytes=104857600
message.max.bytes=104857600
```