# Error while writing a Dataframe from Spark to Kafka (org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am writing a Dataframe with 30000 entries into kafka using the below params

```
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_brokers)
    .option("kafka.compression.type","lz4")
    .option("kafka.max.request.size", 1048576)
    .option("kafka.message.max.bytes", 750000)
    .option("kafka.max.request.size",750000)
    .option("kafka.max.partition.fetch.bytes",750000)
    .option("kafka.batch.size", 100)
    .option("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    .option("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.JsonSerializer")
    .option("topic", product_kafka_topic)
    .option("partition",15)
```

I am not getting is how Spark is partitioning the Dataframe, I get the error

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 10540452 bytes when serialized which is larger than 750000, which is the value of the max.request.size configuration.
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: You are are defining twice the same option max.request.size. Also, the error message pretty much explains what the problem here is...

Comment: its pushing 10 MB chunk of data, I have kept limit as 750 KB

Comment: Exactly. So it is denied

Answer (score 1):

> The message is 10540452 bytes when serialized which is larger than 750000

You have explicitly capped the message size

```
.option("kafka.message.max.bytes", 750000)
```

> I am not getting is how Spark is partitioning the Dataframe

It takes your columns of `key, value` and optionally `timestamp` and `partition`, then packages each row into Kafka records, which are produced in request batches.

```
.option("kafka.max.request.size", 1048576)
.option("kafka.max.request.size", 750000)
```

Given that you repeated the option with a second value, that is the value that'll be used in the config

More than one message can be in a request, but this value is bytes, not number of records.

```
.option("kafka.batch.size", 100)
```

This isn't something that can be fixed in Spark alone; the broker will also deny large messages -- See solutions here [How can I send large messages with Kafka (over 15MB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb)

---

*Aside*: Structured Streaming does not use `key.serializer` or `value.serializer`, or `partition` as configuration options

Comment: I cannot change kafka, not in my control
I put .repartition(2500,  col("pbpdID"),col("productName"),col("seasonName"), col("createdDate") )

it partitioned the data, but 2% of data is still problematic, guess need to filter

Comment: When you write the data to the topic, it only accepts those columns that I listed, not other names.