# What will happen if Apache Kafka gets 2 MB message? Since default size is just 1 MB

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I went through web like [How can I send large messages with Kafka (over 15MB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb), but looking to understand, since Max default size of Kafka is 1 MB and will happen if producer sends more than 1 MB data (ex: 2MB) to kafka topic?

What behavior do we see ?

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens?

Comment: The batch is rejected