# Configure Kafka to send large files(messages)

Tags: apache-kafka

I have researched different configs even from Stackoverflow, but really stucked with it for several days so created separate question for it. I am trying to configure Kafka to send large messages (10-50 mbytes). I run Kafka in Docker (version is confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.2.1). I also understand that Kafka is the not the best instrument for it. I am trying to config Kafka from Java the way below, and restarted my Kafka Docker instance, but still see the error message:

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The request
> included a message larger than the max message size the server will
> accept.

And below is config which I use (from Google and Stackoverflow).

1. Here are my Producer and Consumer and KafkaAdmin java classes:
   **KafkaAdminConfig.java**:

   @Bean
   public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
   Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
   configProps.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
   configProps.put("max.message.bytes", String.valueOf(maxFileSize));
   configProps.put("max.request.size", maxFileSize);
   configProps.put("replica.fetch.max.bytes", maxFileSize);
   configProps.put("message.max.bytes", maxFileSize);
   configProps.put("max.message.bytes", maxFileSize);
   configProps.put("max.message.max.bytes", maxFileSize);
   configProps.put("max.partition.fetch.bytes", maxFileSize);
   return new KafkaAdmin(configProps);
   }

**ProducerConfig.java**

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, Byte[]> producerFactoryLargeFiles() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class);

    //required to allow Kafka process files <= 20 mb
    configProps.put("buffer.memory", maxFileSize);
    configProps.put("max.request.size", maxFileSize);
    configProps.put("replica.fetch.max.bytes", maxFileSize);
    configProps.put("message.max.bytes", maxFileSize);
    configProps.put("max.message.bytes", maxFileSize);
    configProps.put("acks", "all");
    configProps.put("retries", 0);
    configProps.put("batch.size", 16384);
    configProps.put("linger.ms", 1);

    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}
```

**ConsumerConfig.java**

```
@Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String>  consumerFactoryLargeFiles() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

        //required to allow Kafka process files <= 20 mb
        props.put("fetch.message.max.bytes", maxFileSize);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }
```

**maxFileSize is 104857600 - it is about 104Mb.** And I am trying to send message about 3MB.

2. I also added following env variables to my docker compose:

> KAFKA_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE: 104857600   KAFKA_PRODUCER_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE:
> 104857600   CONNECT_PRODUCER_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE: 104857600

I will be happy to provide additional information or logs if need.

Comment: Did you actually override the property set?

In any case, this post had more details you can try:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to upload file with other means and send file name via Kafka

Comment: thank you. -I agree your approach is better. And we should follow it in production systems(or use another brokers not kafka for large message processing). But this is the learning task  - to configure Kafka to be able to work with >10mb messages itself.

Comment: This is more of a comment than answer

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by myself - maybe this will be helpful for other people. I followed following manual by Baeldung - https://www.baeldung.com/java-kafka-send-large-message:

1. Kafka topic config via java
2. Kafka broker config via env variable cause I am using Docker:

> KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES: 20971520

3. Kafka Producer config via java
4. Kafka Consumer config via java