# Intermittent Kafka RecordTooLargeException

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using Kafka version 3.2.0 in my local. The message size is about 1.5 MBs. I've added following properties in server.properties and also added **max.request.size** attribute to producer configuration. Approx. 3/100 tries of kafka producing this classification of message fails with following error

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; 
nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 5713 bytes when serialized which is larger than 0, which is the value of the max.request.size configuration.
```

For most of the messages Kafka producer config is loading correctly before KafkaTemplate.send call

```
compression.type=snappy, 
request.timeout.ms=60000, 
reconnect.backoff.ms=200, 
batch.size=500000, 
acks=all, 
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092, 
retry.backoff.ms=500, 
buffer.memory=204857600, 
key.serializer=class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer, 
max.request.size=3000000, 
retries=3, 
value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer, 
max.block.ms=500000, 
linger.ms=30
```

But for the failing call it is :

```
compression.type=snappy, 
request.timeout.ms=60000, 
reconnect.backoff.ms=200, 
batch.size=500000, 
acks=all, 
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092, 
retry.backoff.ms=500, 
buffer.memory=204857600, 
key.serializer=class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer, 
max.request.size=0, 
retries=3, 
value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer, 
max.block.ms=500000, 
linger.ms=30
```

kafka-clients : version 3.1.0
spring-kafka : version 2.9.0

Why is max.request.size still being read as 0 only for few tries but correct for majority others?

Comment: The broker is denying the requests. Edit its settings as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb#21343878