# kafka large message error : KafkaError code=MSG_SIZE_TOO_LARGE,val=10,str="Unable to produce message

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to send message which are larger than one Mb, I set this in server.properties file

```
message.max.bytes=90000000
replica.fetch.max.bytes=90000000
max.message.bytes=90000000
```

but again i get error message: KafkaError{code=MSG_SIZE_TOO_LARGE,val=10,str="Unable to produce message: Broker: Message size too large"}

I also set something in producer.properties

```
max.request.size=90000000
batch.size=90000000
buffer.memory=90000000
```

can anyone help?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb